# Query results in header of query in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, header

I would like to rename column names:

Main Query:

```
SELECT
  gg.value1,
  ff.attribute1,
  ff.attribute2,
  ff.start_date,
  ff.end_date
FROM 
  table1 ff,
  table2 gg
WHERE ff.id = gg.id
```

Current result:

```
value1   attribute1    attribute2   start_date  end_date
------- ----------- -------------- ------------ --------
London    GB            city         1.1.1900    1.1.2000
```

Query from which I would like to rename header of main table:

```
SELECT
  column_name,
  column_promt
FROM
  table3
WHERE column_context = 'ABC'
```

Result table3:

```
column_name      column_promt
------------     -------------
attribute1        state
attribute2        what is it
```

My goal:

```
value1     state       what is it   start_date  end_date
------- ----------- -------------- ------------ --------
London    GB            city         1.1.1900    1.1.2000
```

Comment: SELECT
  gg.value1,
  ff.attribute1 as state,
  ff.attribute2 as "what is it",
  ff.start_date,
  ff.end_date

Comment: Well, yes, @Bryan, that's what you can conclude just by *looking at it*, but I don't think that it is what Dagmar actually wanted. I suspect it is dynamic SQL that should be used here.

Comment: How are you calling the statements? Labelling like this is something that should be handled from the front end, you don’t want to run the same query with different column aliases - it’s a shared pool nightmare and makes code that has to reference the columns difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need dynamic SQL for that. Here's an example.

Instead of join of two tables in the 1st query you posted, I simplified it and created only one sample table; it doesn't really matter for what you're asking.

```
SQL> select * from table1;

VALUE1 ATTRIBUTE1   ATTRIBUTE2      START_DATE END_DATE
------ ------------ --------------- ---------- ----------
London GB           city            01.01.1900 01.01.2000

SQL> select * from table3;

COLUMN_NAME  COLUMN_PROMPT   COLUMN_CONTEXT
------------ --------------- ---------------
attribute1   state           ABC
attribute2   what is it      ABC

SQL>
```

I chose to create a function that returns ref cursor. It composes a `SELECT` statement by outer joining `user_tab_columns` with `table3` as we have to create columns' aliases. To make it simpler, I'm creating aliases for *all* columns, not only the ones contained in `table3`.

`dbms_output.put_line` call isn't necessary, it is here just to emphasize that - when creating dynamic query - it is a good habit to first display statement you composed to make sure it is correct - and then actually run it because dynamic SQL is difficult to debug.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> create or replace function f_test return sys_refcursor is
  2    l_str varchar2(1000);
  3    rc    sys_refcursor;
  4  begin
  5    for cur_r in
  6      (select utc.column_name, nvl(c.column_prompt, utc.column_name) column_alias
  7       from user_tab_columns utc left join table3 c on upper(c.column_name) = utc.column_name
  8                                                   and c.column_context = 'ABC'
  9       where utc.table_name = 'TABLE1'
 10       order by utc.column_id
 11      )
 12    loop
 13        l_str := l_str || cur_r.column_name ||' as "'|| cur_r.column_alias || '",';
 14    end loop;
 15    l_str := 'select ' || rtrim(l_str, ',') || ' from table1';
 16    dbms_output.put_line(l_str);
 17
 18    open rc for l_str;
 19    return rc;
 20  end;
 21  /

Function created.

SQL>
```

Testing: result comes first; trailing `select` statement is result of previously mentioned `dbms_output.put_line` call.

```
SQL> select f_test from dual;
    
F_TEST
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

VALUE1 state      what is it      START_DATE END_DATE
------ ---------- --------------- ---------- ----------
London GB         city            01.01.1900 01.01.2000

select VALUE1 as "VALUE1",ATTRIBUTE1 as "state",ATTRIBUTE2 as "what is
it",START_DATE as "START_DATE",END_DATE as "END_DATE" from table1

SQL>
```

---

As you can see, that's not *trivial* at all, but that's the price you have to pay when having such requirements.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks for advice! Although I still hoped that there is any other way, some simple query adjustment, which could solve it...

Comment: You're welcome. When there's nothing left, you can still hope, no problem in that.